# erorr reading Rgb Images uisng imLIb2

Tags: c, linux, imlib2

I am trying to read a raw RGBA image using imLIb2 (https://docs.enlightenment.org/api/imlib2/html/ -> according to this page it seems like they accept RGBA data for images)

```
    #include <Imlib2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* an image handle */
    Imlib_Image image;

    /* load the image */
    Imlib_Load_Error error;
    image = imlib_load_image_with_error_return("rgba.raw", &error);

    printf("load error:%d", error);

    if (image)
    {
        imlib_context_set_image(image);
        
        imlib_image_set_format("png");
        /* save the image */
        imlib_save_image("working.png");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("not loaded\n");
    }
}
```

loading other images formats like png and Jpeg work properly but when trying to load an RGBA image I get the error "IMLIB_LOAD_ERROR_NO_LOADER_FOR_FILE_FORMAT". Could someone tell me if I am missing something or should add Some header to the RGBA image or should I call some more functions before opening an RGBA image?

If Imlib2 doesn't support reading RgbA images is there any alternative C-library that can read rgb image and do scaling like functions?

Comment: I would suggest http://cimg.eu as a modern, maintained C++ image library - single header file to include (no libraries) and you're done.

Comment: You can easily make a lttle 3-4 line text header for a NetPBM `PAM` file https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PAM_graphics_format and append your raw data to the end to make a file readable by CImg, `feh`, GIMP, Photoshop.

Comment: @bruno you can ignore that part as it won't be executed when loading an RGB image as it turns out to be null.. (i have edited the code to work properly for other images). my main problem is reading an image.

Comment: @mark-setchell thank you for suggesting but I need the library to be in C

Comment: You can make your image into a JPEG/PNG/PAM image at the commandline with **ImageMagick** using `magick -size WxH -depth 8 RGBA:rgba.raw output.png` where `W` and `H` are width and height. Change PNG to PAM if you want (universal) NetPBM format which Imlib2 may be able to understand. If PAM format doesn't work, try PNM.

Comment: @mark-setchell ty I will look into ImageMagick and also NetPBM.

Comment: @mark-setchell in NetPBM is of type RGB triplets and it takes a lot of time to convert it to  PAM file.. ImageMagick comamdnd line seems to work but i am not able to make it work in a c program  "ERROR_MISSING_DELEGATE: no decode delegate" i get this error

Comment: It's very hard to assist without full information. Please click `edit` under your question and update it with a) dimensions in pixels wide by pixels tall and type of your file (RGB, RGBA, grey) also b) the size in bytes of your raw file c) the ImageMagick command you tried and what happened. Thank you.

Comment: @mark-setchell ty I got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this for if someone is facing the same issue

Thanks to @mark-setchell  for contributing!!

magickcore Api  is an alternative C-library that can be used to perform functions on raw RGB.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <magick/ImageMagick.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ExceptionInfo
        exception;

    Image
        *image,
        *images,
        *resize_image,
        *thumbnails;

    ImageInfo
        *image_info;

    /*
      Initialize the image info structure and read an image.
    */
    
    InitializeMagick(NULL);
    GetExceptionInfo(&exception);
    image_info = CloneImageInfo((ImageInfo *)NULL);
    image_info->size = "1920x1080";
    image_info->depth = 8;
    (void)strcpy(image_info->filename, "image.rgba");
    images = ReadImage(image_info, &exception);

    if (images == (Image *)NULL)
        exit(1);

    resize_image = MinifyImage(images, &exception);

    if (resize_image == (Image *)NULL)
        printf("error \n");

    DestroyImageInfo(image_info);
    
    DestroyMagick();
    return (0);
}
```

for reading raw images the depth and the WxH have to be specified for the image. the above is a very small example for reducing the size in half.  (https://imagemagick.org/script/magick-core.php).